# If you hear a mountain lion screaming, how close is it?

Tags: animal-behaviour, cougars

Female mountain lions will scream to [attract a mate](https://www.nps.gov/brca/learn/nature/mountainlion.htm), and males will do it as well.

This [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxo8X5uIWRE) and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UE7YOJVSoIs) both have audio of what it sounds like.

Given how loud it sounds, would there be any way of estimating how far away the mountain lion is?

Comment: Now that you have a rough estimate of how far away the mountain lion is, the next question has to be how fast can she cover that distance to get to the ultra-fresh cat food that is you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There does not seem to be much information over the net on the distance one can hear a [mountain lion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cougar), but I did find this little tidbit:

> The frightening puma scream is the long range call. It has been described as like a high pitched and short roar of one of the big cats.
>
> Then there is the shrill whistle like call. This call has been used by a tame puma after she received a bit of food after the person called her over. The person described the sound as a high pitched, cheeping, whistle. It can travel a good distance (300 yards).
>
> The same whistle call has been heard by researchers in the mountains of New Mexico between members of a family group and up to 300 meters from each other. The whistle would seem to vary between pumas. **Mountain lion sounds** are varied and some others are that have been heard between males and females are: a low gargling growl, throaty yowls and squeaks. The squeaks and growls traveled about **50-100 metres** while the yowls traveled **200 meters**. - [Mountain Lion Sounds](http://pictures-of-cats.org/mountain-lion-sounds.html)

[image: Mountain Lion]

> **NOTE** – Cougars (also called pumas, mountain lions, catamounts, Florida panthers, painters, ghost cats, etc) are considered part of the lesser/small cat classification when it comes to their ability to purr and not roar. - [Do big cats roar or purr - or both?](http://www.wildcatsanctuary.org/do-big-cats-roar-or-purr/)